# error in Expandable List View in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm new in android 
and i want to make an expandable list according to this code:

```java
public class ListexpActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    ExpandableListView  epView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
        epView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandablelistview01);
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        epView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        epView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick( ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int groupPosition, long arg3 ) {
                if (groupPosition == 5) {
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        epView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id ) {
                if (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 0) {
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        // Sample data set. children[i] contains the children (String[]) for
        // groups[i].
        private String[]    groups      = { "Parent1", "Parent2", "Parent3" };
        private String[][]  children    = { { "Child1" }, { "Child2" }, { "Child3" }, { "Child4" }, { "Child5" } };

        public Object getChild( int groupPosition, int childPosition ) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId( int groupPosition, int childPosition ) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount( int groupPosition ) {
            int i = 0;
            try {
                i = children[groupPosition].length;

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return i;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

            TextView textView = new TextView(ListexpActivity.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // textView.setTextColor(R.color.marcyred);
            // Set the text starting position
            textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
            return textView;
        }

        public View getChildView( int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public Object getGroup( int groupPosition ) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId( int groupPosition ) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public View getGroupView( int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable( int groupPosition, int childPosition ) {

            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and in xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandablelistview01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

but when implement the program in emulator the error is

```
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ola.listexp.Main/ola.listexp.Main.ListexpActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ExpandableListActivity.onContentChanged(ExpandableListActivity.java:222)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at ola.listexp.Main.ListexpActivity.onCreate(ListexpActivity.java:31)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    05-11 14:38:24.507: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

i so from the internet that i should change `@+id/expandablelistview01` to `@android/idexpandablelistview01`

```
but i have another error in 

    NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.

Unable to resolve id "@andriod:id/expandablelistview01" for attribute "id"`
```

so help me !

Comment: if you use Eclipse press CTRL+Shift+F for code formatting.

Comment: For your question: You're sure about removing + from ? @+id/expandablelistview01` ? afaik the + introduces the id to the system.

Answer (score 0):

There error is indeed related to the id of your expandedlist. From your error code there is the following line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

What it is telling you is that in your XML file the ID associated with the list MUST be @android:id/list

That should clear things up :)